# Who is the hitman?

Tags: logical-deduction, mystery

You are an agent in the FBI and you have been assigned to another investigation.  A murder has been committed in an undisclosed location and it is your job to identify the suspect.  Your team has concluded that this murder was the work of a secret organization of hitmen, but you do not know much about this group.  You have been tasked with finding out the name of the organization and the murderer's first and last name so you can bring them to justice.  Good luck.

--Your first lead: [google.com](http://google.com/) - HINT: rgb (what colors do you see?)

The first hint I say will lead you on your way.  The secret in this game?  The free web domain (stackpuzzler.wixsite.com/b*****) - A hint to help you see things unseen: take advantage of highlighting the screen.

SPOILER HINT: "Where mail is sent by the killer's crew..."

> The colors referenced before mean google.  Google has an email service called gmail.  The "@..."  means that you should have this: "@gmail.com".  The password for this email is found in the syllables in the name "dandelion".  What does that really say?  That is as far as I am willing to take you.

Comment: Very likely related: **[Is using a personal website to host content for a puzzle frowned upon?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4992)** (*spoilers*: yes, it is frowned upon).  This certainly looks like a case of you hosting (parts of) a puzzle off-site.  Is that the case?

Comment: Based on the first partial answer, we're clearly now in territory *just asked about* on our Meta regarding [Internet-wide puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6299).  **Puzzles really need to be self-contained *here*** — a "puzzle" post that is little more than a breadcrumb to off-site content is not appropriate, for the reasons expressed in the Meta posts referenced.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic for the reasons already stated.  If you wish to post the content locally instead, make those changes and flag a moderator to request your puzzle be considered for reopening.  (See also: [Where should binary files be stored?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6070), for practical suggestions on how to provide non-textual content in your puzzle in an acceptable way.)

Comment: I am new to this site, so I was not aware of the scope of the puzzles shared through this stack exchange. But I think you guys should keep this question open because nathoenk has come very close to solving this riddle. I do see where you are coming from, as I do reference other sites, but I dont think that is really a problem, as I mostly reference sites like google or youtube.  I spent a lot of work orchestrating this puzzle, from the rhymes to the website links, and it would be very interesting if someone could solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer not yet finished** :
first :

> transform google logo to color first letter
>  `G O O G L E`
>  `B R Y B G R`
>  then go to link [stackpuzzler.wixsite.com/brybgr](https://stackpuzzler.wixsite.com/brybgr)

second :

> I assume there are 4 segments on that page
>  1. "Wait for the ="
>  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxP4LuS26ds
>  0:45 - 0:56
>  2. YT 1-4: zEfy
>  3. The next clue is the right one for you: red, green, yellow, blue, you know these colors too.  Where mail is sent by the killer's crew.
>  Entrance: .--. ..- --.. --.. .-.. . .-. -- .- .. .-.. .--.-. .-.-.- .-.-.- .-.-.-
>  [image: this image is on the side]
>  4. Oh wait, there's more!  This is what you've been looking for:  The secret key is in the puzzler's name.  What does it really say?  Three words, no space, this will help you solve the case.

third :

> segment no.1 tell how to finish this riddle
>  the answer is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=
>  still missing video id that contains 11 digits
>  segment no.2 YT 1-4: zEfy means :
>  YT = YouTube
>  1-4 = first 4 digit
>  zEfy is the digit
>  segment no.3 morse code means :
>  `.--. ..- --.. --.. .-.. . .-. -- .- .. .-.. .--.-. .-.-.- .-.-.- .-.-.-`
>  `PUZZLERMAIL@...`
>  I still have not found the rest(images) clue, there are some Greece Alphabet, I've re-order, play with colors and images, but nothing, unless there are 4 images so I assume each image represents 1 digit
>  segment no.4 puzzler's name, still got nothing too
>  `Dandelion`? -> 3 words(or letter or digit?)
>  from segment 2,3,4 we got 4 digits + 4 digits + 3 digits = 11 digits video id

I still want to do more research about this.

Comment: you are very close to the answer